# Передача имени файла как параметра в программу на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть код программы на Python, программу я запускаю через терминал и входные данные у меня находятся в файле input.txt, как мне в качестве аргумента передать название файла и чтобы это заработало?

Comment: Например `python3 main.py input.txt`, тогда из `sys.argv` вытаскиваете путь к файлу `input.txt`, открываете его и работаете

Comment: Если же через `input()` хотите считывать, тогда: `python3 main.py < input.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При таком запуске
`python script.py input.txt` или таком
`script.py input.txt`

Можно так:

```
import sys

try:
    file_name = sys.argv[1] # получаем 1й элемент списка (в примерах выше именно он отвечает за имя файла)
except IndexError: 
    file_name = 'input.txt' # если нам не передают имя файла, то "выбираем" его сами
```

Comment: @nitr0xs объясните написанный код пожалуйста

Comment: @David добавил комментарии

Comment: я сейчас попробовал, но к большому сожалению выводится ошибка - IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @David Traceback, пожалуйста

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/David374/PycharmProjects/test1/venv/Main.py", line 3, in <module>
    str = sys.argv[1]

Comment: Всё, я разобрался, Спасибо большое!